# Docker Nexus Login Connection refused

Tags: docker, nexus, docker-desktop

I am trying to setup Nexus 3.0 as a private registry for Docker in Windows 10. I am using Docker Desktop[Latest].

[image: repository setting]

**Also, added Docker Realm**

[image]

[image]

**Docker Daemon config**

But when I tried to login, I am getting connection refused error.

[image]

What am I missing here?
EDIT : Any pointers please...

Comment: Could you please share docker run command or docker-compose.yaml?

Comment: You mean nexus? Nexus is a standalone installation, not running from container

Comment: Docker client is trying to dial your registry over the ipv6 loopback (`[::1]`). Is nexus configured to listen on that ? Try `docker login -u admin 127.0.0.1:8085` and see if it gives a different result.

Comment: Hi, same error."is nexus configured for that?" - what change should i make for that?